# How to fix (MAKEPKG) installation problem?

Tags: linux, archlinux

I want to install yay for downloading package from AUR ArchLinux,
I don't know what to do?!
Thanks for your helping.

When I use git clone and then use the makepkg -si  command , it gives me this error:

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
cd yay
makepkg -si
```

Error text:

```
==> ERROR: Cannot find the fakeroot binary.
==> ERROR: Cannot find the strip binary required for object file stripping.
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're missing the libraries to compile the package. To install them:

```
sudo pacman -S binutils make gcc pkg-config fakeroot
```

or, to install basic tools for compiling code:

```
sudo pacman -S base-devel
```

Also instead of installing and compiling yay (which also requires you to install all the GO libraries) why not installing the precompiled yay-bin? It's the same package.

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay-bin.git
cd yay-bin
makepkg -si
```

Answer (score 3):

try with that:

```
sudo pacman -S binutils make gcc pkg-config fakeroot
```

then again try to makepkg.